# Moving div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know what the problem with this code is. It is meant to change the amount of pixels of position right by 2 for as long as the right button is clicked. But for some reason i am not aware of, the div just moves to the right once and that's it.

```js
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

    function KeyPressed(k) {
    
    var LeftBtn = 37;
    var RightBtn = 39;
    var UpBtn = 38;
    var DownBtn = 40;
    
    var Player = document.getElementById("Player");
    var BeginningPos = 0;
    
    if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
        BeginningPos = BeginningPos + 20;
        Player.style.left = BeginningPos + "px"; 
    }
    
    }
```

```css
#Background { 
    height:400px; 
    width:600px; 
    outline: 5px solid black; 
    position:relative; } 
 
    #Player { 
    position:absolute; 
    height:20px; 
    width:40px; 
    outline: 5px solid black; 
    background-color:red; left: 0; 
    font-size:10px;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="GameBackground">
    <div id="Player"></div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include a Stack Snippet in your question.

Comment: you're resetting your BeginningPos variable every time. So you end up in the same place every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function resets BeginningPos to zero each time it is called.

Moving var BeginningPos= 0 outside the function is one easy way to fix it.

```
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;
var BeginningPos = 0;

function KeyPressed(k) {

  var LeftBtn = 37;
  var RightBtn = 39;
  var UpBtn = 38;
  var DownBtn = 40;

  var Player = document.getElementById("Player"); 


  if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
    console.log(BeginningPos);
    BeginningPos = BeginningPos + 20;
    Player.style.left = BeginningPos + "px"; 
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tlynch001/t1r86Lf0/

Comment: FYI - The variable name is BeginningPos. Maybe update the text in your answer to reflect the OPs code?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `BeginningPos` needs to go out of the function, now this value will always be 0 with every button click so the button will move once and thats it.

```
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;
var BeginningPos = 0;
function KeyPressed(k) {

   var LeftBtn = 37;
   var RightBtn = 39;
   var UpBtn = 38;
   var DownBtn = 40;

   var Player = document.getElementById("Player");

   if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
      BeginningPos = BeginningPos + 20;
      Player.style.left = BeginningPos + "px"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the function KeyPressed is run `BeginningPos` is being redeclared and set to 0. See the following codepen and look at the console.log

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXJBOY

A quick and dirty fix would be the following

```
var BeginningPos = 0;

document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(k) {

var LeftBtn = 37;
var RightBtn = 39;
var UpBtn = 38;
var DownBtn = 40;

var Player = document.getElementById("Player");

if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
    BeginningPos = BeginningPos + 20;
    Player.style.left = BeginningPos + "px"; 
}

}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

that because in each keydowm event you set start left position = 0;

```
var BeginningPos = 0;
```

But you need to get current rectangle position before moving it right

```
var pos = Player.getBoundingClientRect();
var BeginningPos = pos.x;
```

this is some quick solution, but it may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is only logical Error. the scope of 'BeginningPos' variable made inside the function.
declare it outside the function.
fixed code:

```
[var BeginningPos = 0;

function KeyPressed(k) {

var LeftBtn = 37;
var RightBtn = 39;
var UpBtn = 38;
var DownBtn = 40;

var Player = document.getElementById("Player");

if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
    BeginningPos = BeginningPos + 20;
    Player.style.left = BeginningPos + "px"; 
}

}
window.addEventListener('keydown',KeyPressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your keyPressed() function you declare the beginningPos=0

```
function KeyPressed(k) {

var LeftBtn = 37;
var RightBtn = 39;
var UpBtn = 38;
var DownBtn = 40;

var Player = document.getElementById("Player");
var BeginningPos = 0; //Right here to be exact

if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
    BeginningPos = BeginningPos + 20;
    Player.style.left = BeginningPos + "px"; 
}

}
```

You need to declare BeginningPos outside of the function, becuase currently it sets it to 0, then adds 20 everytime you hit right, resulting in it appearing to only move once.